# WorkAround create a look up column

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I want to create a Look up column to bring the data of a column "Person/Group" in other library but I can´t. 
I found some solutions to this inconvenient, for example:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56745/is-it-possible-to-make-a-lookup-column-that-looks-up-person-or-group-type-from

But, I can't use them because the politics of the company I'm working, forbade me to code in Sharepoint or even use Sharepoint Designer.
So... is there a workaround this problem, maybe working with InfoPath or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the list settings graphical user interface of SharePoint?

Have a look at

[Sharepoint: Calculated column based on another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164461/sharepoint-calculated-column-based-on-another-list/6167215#6167215)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShLH0mBcA54

== Update after some discussions ==

Lookup columns can only be linked to other lists and the only built-in list that contains any users is the hidden User Information List. This list you can link to, to do it any other way you must create your own list with users

Comment: Hi, this is not quite what I was looking for.

I know how to make a Look up column, but I want to know is how to make a Look up Column that references or brings a field "Person/Group".

Comment: Lookup columns can only be linked to other lists and the only built-in list that contains any users is the hidden User Information List. This list you can link to, to do it any other way you must create your own list with users.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way to handle this.